# BibTex: Change Bd. to Vol. without changing language

Tags: bibtex, natbib, german

I use the bibgerm-package for bibtex. My problem is: I need the german version of citation inside the text: [Meier und Hendriksen] but I need the english short form of volume, instead of the german one for "Band": `Bd.` has to change to `Vol.`

How can I achieve that?

Change language but make sure the "und" stays, or
change the label of volume from `Bd.` to `Vol.`?

Oh apparantly I use `natbib`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. Can you show a tiny sample document that shows what you are doing? It should just show how you are loading the language package (`babel`?) and the bibliography package and style.

Comment: I stopped using natbib 6 years ago and switched to biblatex. As i remember it, and please correct me, if I am completely wrong here, you need to change the translations in your *.bst files. Search for the German terms like 'Band' or 'Bd.' or 'Hrsg.' and change them to the abbreviations or translations you want. Like 'Vol.', 'Hg.' or 'eds.'. I don't want to be missioary here, but biblatex offers way easier possibilities to change these things without messing with 'hardcoded' things.

Comment: For biblatex, one can also put `\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{Vol.~#1}` in the preamble to change `Bd.` to `Vol.` (without the need to adjust existing installed files)